# HELP! sIFR Text Wrapping

Tags: sifr

http://doc.bigheadservices.com/my-page.php

In the navigation bar, under the logo, the FAQ block is wrapping, cutting off the Q. How do I fix this?

Comment: The link provided doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I fixed it by adding 1px padding around the element. The text was a link within an list-item. The sIFR was applied to the <li>. Adding 1px padding to the <a> fixed it.

Not sure if it is the proper way, but it works and I've got tons more work to do.